# Grouping Tkinter entry widgets and creating a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, user-interface, tkinter, iteration

I'm new to Tkinter and just wondering if there is anyway I could group some entry boxes like in a list and then do a for loop on them.

I'm watching this tutorial video and on clicking a button they want the button to clear all the entry boxes and they've done it like this:

```
# Create Submit fn for database
def submit():
    f_name.delete(0, END)
    l_name.delete(0, END)
    address.delete(0, END)
    city.delete(0, END)
    postcode.delete(0, END)

# Create entry textboxes
f_name = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=30).grid(column=1, row=0)
l_name = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=30).grid(column=1, row=1)
address = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=30).grid(column=1, row=2)
city = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=30).grid(column=1, row=3)
postcode = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=30).grid(column=1, row=4)

# Create submit button
submit_btn = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Add Record", width=20, command=submit).grid(column=0, row=6, pady=10)
```

Instead of the `submit` function being repetitive I would like to do something like this:

```
def submit():

entries = ttk.Entry(mainframe)

for entry in entries:
    entry.delete(0, END)
```

That function immediately above doesn't work but I'm looking for something along those lines to avoid the unneccessary repetition and have cleaner code. Is this possible?

Comment: Widgets are objects, and objects can be added to a list. Have you tried creating a list and adding your widgets to it?

Comment: Yes, I've tried but not really sure how to access the objects: `entries = []  for ttk.Entry in mainframe: entries.append(ttk.Entry)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Widgets are objects, and objects can be added to a list. You do it no differently than you do strings or integers or any other type of object.

```
f_name = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=30)
l_name = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=30)
address = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=30)
city = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=30)
postcode = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=30)

f_name.grid(column=1, row=0)
l_name.grid(column=1, row=1)
address.grid(column=1, row=2)
city.grid(column=1, row=3)
postcode.grid(column=1, row=4)

entries = [f_name, l_name, address, city, postcode]
...
for entry in entries:
    entry.delete(0, END)
```

You can also use a dictionary instead of individual variables. You can then iterate over the dictionary like you do any other dictionary:

```
entries = {
    "f_name": ttk.Entry(...),
    "l_name": ttk.Entry(....),
    ...
}
```

Comment: Also I was wondering if there was a way I could create the list dynamically, perhaps using `.grid_slaves()`?. The problem is `.gird_slaves()` only takes `row` and `column` as parameters so I can't specify it to Entry objects. `entries = []   for item in mainframe.grid_slaves(column=1):  entries.append(item)`

Comment: @sarchi-xo: _"Also I was wondering if there was a way I could create the list dynamically, perhaps using .grid_slaves()?."_ - yes, there are ways to do that.